# ChatOvercharged - making inserting markdown links in chat convenient

Tags: script, chat, hyperlinks, typescript

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: userscript preview]

### About

Chat Overcharged is a userscript that aims to improve the quality of life of chat users. It is a living project, and more features are going to be added as the userscript matures.

The initial release (v1.5.1) focuses on making inserting links into messages easier:

- If you had any text selected, the link title will be prefilled accordingly.
- If no text was selected, the script will attempt to fetch and use the page title as one.
- Choosing "add link" inserts a Markdown-formatted (`[title](url)`) link at cursor position.
- If any text is selected before clicking "add link", it will be replaced by the formatted link.
- The modal can be freely dragged around.

**Change log**

| Version | Updates |
| --- | --- |
| 1.6.0 | Stack Overflow & Stack Exchange comment link titles are fetched from the API and constructed as `<comment body> by <author> on <short date>` |
| 1.6.1 | StackApps, SuperUser, and AskUbuntu added to the list of sites with titles fetched from the API |
| 1.6.2 | Modal dragging is now supported in Firefox (see this [old bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11656061/11407695) for details) |
| 1.7.0 | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>) + <kbd>L</kbd> shortcut minimizes the modal if it is already open |
| 1.8.0 | If selected text is a link, it will be inserted into the link input, and the title will be fetched if possible |
| 1.8.1 | Userscript no longer prevents normal drag and drop in chat |
| 1.9.0 | Keyboard shortcuts for text formatting |

**Keyboard shortcuts**

| Shortcut | Action | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>) + <kbd>L</kbd> | toggles the modal | in Chrome, supercedes the [browser's one](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179) only if chat input is focused |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>) + <kbd>B</kbd> | adds **bold** formatting to the current selection |  |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>) + <kbd>I</kbd> | adds *emphasis* formatting to the current selection |  |
| <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>) + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> | adds <strike>strikeout</strike> formatting to the current selection | <kbd>Shift</kbd> ensures the shortcut doesn't interfere with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> browser shortcut |
| <kbd>Esc</kbd> | minimizes the modal | only active if the modal is already open |

#### License

The script is licensed under the [GPL-3.0-or-later](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later) license.

#### Download

[Install](https://github.com/userscripters/chat-overcharged/raw/master/dist/modern/index.user.js) | [Minified](https://github.com/userscripters/chat-overcharged/raw/master/dist/modern/index.min.user.js)

The script *does not need* a userscript manager to work (but shipped with the necessary headers anyway).

#### Platform

Version number means "last tested on":

| Chrome | Opera | Firefox | Edge | IE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ✔ 104.0.5112.81 | ✔ 77.0.4054.203 | ✔ 89.0 | ✔ 92.0.902.55 | no ** |

** If you need explicit support for IE or other unlisted browsers, buy me a coffee first. :)

### Contact

Author: [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter)

Organization: [UserScripters](https://github.com/userscripters)

Please, submit bug reports [on the source repository](https://github.com/userscripters/chat-overcharged/issues).

Before adding a new one, please check if it hasn't been raised before.

You can also [drop by to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214345/userscript-newbies-and-friends), we are a friendly bunch.

### Code

[Source code](https://github.com/userscripters/chat-overcharged/blob/master/src/index.ts) written in TypeScript.

Contributions are welcome, you can always submit a [PR here](https://github.com/userscripters/chat-overcharged/pulls).

Comment: Are you sure coffee is strong enough to get you past every IE quirk?

Comment: @rene depends on the version of IE :) 9-11th should be bearable with a dark roast brew

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**It seems to block dragging links into the text-area:**

[image: chat overcharted not letting me drag and drop]

---

**When I turn the script off, dragging and dropping works fine:**

[image: without chat overcharged]

Answer (score 2):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, it opens the modal, but when I repress <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, it doesn't close it.

Simply, what I mean is that it could be toggled by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

I am not sure if this is by design but I think it is a feature request.

Comment: That's kinda by design - the initial implementation was exactly as you specified, but at some point I decided to opt for `Esc` to close the modal as a more semantic approach. I'd mark it "status-needs-more-input" :)

Comment: @OlegValter OK. I have marked it as [status-bydesign] since `ESC` is already close the modal, anyway, I would be happy if you change your mind to convert it to be toggle in the future. :)